# Error while trying to create tables using SQlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm having hard time trying to create Three tables and insert values to them.

The SQlite queries are correct since it worked with only one table before i have tried to make three tables and insert values to them.

Also,i put only part of GameOver class and i declared the Datatypes.
Thanks for the help.

```
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.COL1;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.COL2;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.COL3;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.TABLE_NAME_Easy;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.TABLE_NAME_Hard;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.TABLE_NAME_Normal;
import static com.avrahamzilberblat.battleshipfinal.Constants.TAG;

public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public DatabaseHelper(Context context,String tableName) {

        super(context, tableName, null, 5);

        SQLiteDatabase dbEasy=this.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase dbNormal=this.getWritableDatabase();
        SQLiteDatabase dbHard=this.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Hard + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Normal + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Hard + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
        db.execSQL("DROP IF TABLE EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME_Easy);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public boolean addData(String tableName,PlayerDetails playerDetails) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL2,playerDetails.getWinnerName());
        contentValues.put(COL3, playerDetails.getRatio());


        long result = db.insert(tableName, null, contentValues);

        //if date as inserted incorrectly it will return -1
        if (result == -1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
```

---

```
public class GameOver extends AppCompatActivity {

 public void addData(String tableName,PlayerDetails playerDetails)
        {
            mDatabasehelper=new DatabaseHelper(this,tableName);

            boolean insertData=mDatabasehelper.addData(tableName,playerDetails);
            if(insertData)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Data Successfully added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Something Went Wrong ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: You are trying to create the table `TABLE_NAME_Hard` twice, change the 1st statement to `TABLE_NAME_Easy`

Comment: Uninstall the app so the db is deleted and rerun again.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to create the same table (_Hard) a second time. It would appear that you want to create _Easy. The following change is what I believe you want :-

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Easy + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Normal + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME_Hard + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            COL2 +" TEXT,"+COL3+" REAL)");
}
```

Note that after making the changes you will need to do one of the following before rerunning the App :-

1. Delete(Clear) the App's Data via settings/Apps.
2. Uninstall the App.

   - Note increasing the version number would not work as the code in the **onUpGrade** method doesn't delete all the tables.

*P.S. it would be simpler/better to have an indicator for the difficulty (Easy, Normal, Hard) and thus a single table rather than three (allows you to more easily say select all bu easy e.g. `SELECT * FROM the_one_table WHERE difficulty = 'normal' OR difficulty = 'hard'`)*

- *Note although the above uses text/string for the difficulty using an integer e.g. 0 for easy, 2 for normal, 4 for hard (leaves some scope for other difficulties), would be more efficient.*